# Storing command output in array?

Tags: ksh, aix

When I am trying to storing **ls -ltr *.sh** output in an variable it is working fine, But when I am trying to store in array it is throwing me error. How to store the commands output in array, As same as it is storing in variable.

> Example(1):

```
set -A arr $(ls -ltr *.sh)
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

Error:

> -rw-r--r--: bad option(s)

why this error is coming, How this array treating the command ouput. I have tried as below.

> Example(2):

```
set -A arr "$(ls -ltr *.sh)"
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

Error: here output is coming in single row, And saying badoptions. how to print output of array in line by line.

> -rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Apr 23 07:06 tt2.sh^J-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Apr 23 07:06 tt1.sh^J-rw-r--r--    1 root     system            0 Apr 23 07:06 test.sh^J-rw-r--r--    1 root     system           49 Apr 23 07:09 tt.sh: bad option(s)

Answer (score 0):

I know been a while...but just in case.

1. Bad option can be avoided by using `set -A arr -- $(ls -ltr *.sh)`

But you'll end up with an array that will store the data not line per line but with a new index each space.

2. The error with echo (you should use print instead by the way) can be avoided with the same `--`
3. I don't know any oneliner that would do what you want. I would do this with a loop myself. Something like that :

   ```
   #!/bin/ksh

   j=0

   while read line; do
           array[$j]="$line"
           ((j++))
   done <<< "$(ls -ltr *.sh)"

   print ${#array[*]}
   print -- ${array[2]}
   ```

Hope it can still helps